# Jquery how add an element to dom

Tags: jquery, dom

Hello I have a function that add combobox into the page, and I need to use the values of these combobox. When I try to acces into the jquery code it don't work.
I think that I need to add the element to dom but I don't know how to do that.
The id of combo is 'selectCombo'

Comment: Show us what you did so far regarding the code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a DOM element with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395525/how-do-i-add-a-dom-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices:

- .prepend() http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
- .append() http://api.jquery.com/append/
- .insertAfter() http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/
- .insertBefore() http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Comment: `.add` is not adding to the DOM.

Comment: true! "Add elements to the set of matched elements." -- jquery docs. removed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 $("<div/>", {

  // PROPERTIES HERE

  text: "Click me",

  id: "example",

  "class": "myDiv",      // ('class' is still better in quotes)

  css: {           
     color: "red",
     fontSize: "3em",
     cursor: "pointer"
  },

  on: {
    mouseenter: function() {
      console.log("PLEASE... "+ $(this).text());
    },
    click: function() {
      console.log("Hy! My ID is: "+ this.id);
    }
  },

  append: "<i>!!</i>",

  appendTo: "body"      // Finally, append to any selector

});
```