# How to create the DOM element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a DOM element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395525/how-do-i-add-a-dom-element-with-jquery)

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b(" + l + ")\\b")
var sOpen = "<span class='highlight'>";
var sClose = "</span>";
var newhtml = sp.replace(re, sOpen + l + sClose, "gi");
alert(newhtml);
$('.highlight').css('color', 'yellow');
```

I am getting newHtml value as

I love to work with `<span class='highlight'>jquery</span>`

I am highlight the highlight class item. jquery but its not hightlighting the text. please can any body tell me is that something I am doing wrong here?

how to create a newhtml as DOm element?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395525/how-do-i-add-a-dom-element-with-jquery

Comment: You need to append to the DOM is some fashion.  Using .after, .before, .append.

Comment: Is there some reason you're using jQuery to add CSS styles to the .highlight elements instead of just using a stylesheet?

Comment: yes I need to hightlight the text inside the span/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better would be to wrap it with the built-in logic:

```
$('myelement').wrap('<span/>').parent().addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object of it and add it to the DOM:

```
var newhtml = $(sp.replace(re, sOpen + l + sClose, "gi"));
$(body).append(newhtml);
```

Comment: Thanks Baszz, so if I need to highlight the element jquery what do I need to do? thanks

Comment: You can just refer to the element through the newhtml variable (newhtml.addClass()) for example. You can also add the id attribute to it and refer to the element that way ($('myid').addClass() for example)