# Add div Element with class using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="status">
  <span class="bar"></span>
    <div class="ep">Ep 12</div>
</div>
```

I want to add another div like "ep" div in span with class "dub" with javascript or Jquery

Comment: good . go for it. who stops you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

newDiv.classList.add('class-name');

document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].append(newDiv);
```

Comment: tnx, but in the div i want to add text like the example Ep 12

Comment: @ChamsAgouni Then you would add `newDiv.textContent = 'Ep 12'`

Comment: @ChamsAgouni If that worked for you I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer.

Comment: it worked but i got a new problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily find the answer by search it on internet .

There are many ways to do this. But I do it with the easiest way.
Give your span a id because changes we done to the class will affect all it’s members.
So I give ep_bar as id.

```
<div class="status">
  <span class="bar" id=”ep_bar”></span>
    <div class="ep">Ep 12</div>
</div>
```

Then import jquery.
After that,

```
Var div1 = '<div class="ep">Ep 13</div>'
$(“#ep_bar”).append(div1);
```

Or else find another way/s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395525/how-do-i-add-a-dom-element-with-jquery) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749314/using-jquery-to-dynamically-create-div)

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
var $div = $("<div />");
$div.addClass("ep").html("Ep 12");

var $span = $("<span />");
$span.addClass("dub");

$div.appendTo($span);
</code>
```

And then append your span wherever you need